# pushing the boundaries of ASP.NET HttpRuntime.Cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have an ASP.NET webapp. This webapp is installed on the same server for around 30 different clients, so the webapp is running in more than 30 domains, but on the same server.

The webapp has several controls that are common for each page. Those controls are declared in a master page that every web form in the app uses. These controls are loaded from a MySQL database.

The controls are: 3 nested combo boxes, 4 different menus, and 2 data lists.

Should I cache every control in order to get data from data base only when the information is changed or it would be too much?

I'm not sure if it would be bad for the performance to cache too many things.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, is create a UserControl that holds all this shared controls, and use the built in [OutputCache directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx).